# Extract messages from IBM Websphere MQ

Tags: java, ibm-mq

How to extract messages from MQ(message queue)?
Message format in my requirement is `String` type.
Please advice some sites.

Comment: [Look at this link](http://www.capitalware.biz/mq_code_java.html), it is full of MQ sample code for Java.

Comment: Are you using JMS ? Are you running inside WebSphere, or another Application Server ? The way the question is phrased it indicates you just want to read from a standalone program. Also please accept the proper answer if one is satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried: [Connect MQ using Java](http://www.live-on-google.com/connect-mq-using-java) ?

There are also many IBM materials about Websphere MQ. Start with [Using Java](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.java.doc/com/ibm/mq/MQC.html)

I think you must give us more details about problems. Which version of Websphere MQ do you have? What platform? Is it local to your machine? Have you read manual and set `QM_APPLE` and `QM_ORANGES` queues? Which Java interface do you want to use: JMS or native?

Comment: . I am new to this one.can you assist me on this.

Comment: . i tried  "Connect MQ using Java" . not able to understand 
          completely. and also there is no main class.could you please
          tell me how to run it.

Comment: Have you read fine IBM manuals about Websphere MQ and have you completed their tutorial? I started with it and nice Python classes, then I tried to use it with my Java application.